# Unable to run a springboot project which runs fine from Netbean

Tags: spring-boot, cmd

Could you helpme?

I have a springboot project which runs flowlessly from Netbeans->run project (F9)

However when I try to run it from Windos 10 CMD it shows an error. The command I use is:

```
java -jar myproject.jar -Dspring.config.location=myproject.properties
```

One tip: I have two properties file: myproject.properties and myproject-dev.properties and I don't know how to specify this from CMD

The error shown is:

> ---
>
> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
> Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
> Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
> Action:
> Consider the following:
> If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
> If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (**no profiles are currently active**).

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think the problem is the application is not getting the configuration from both properties files but I don't  know how to specify this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it solve. The problem was the parameters

The proper command to run is

> java -jar  myaplication.jar -Dserver.error.include-message=always --spring.config.location=/<path_to_properties_folder>/myaplication.properties --spring.profiles.active=dev